# Python Docstring: how to document a function that returned an other function?

Tags: python, flask, docstring

I do Flask app. How to document a function that returned an other function?

```
@mod.route('/report')
def function():
    """"
    Function call 'function_2' for display report
    :return: function_2
    :rtype: 
    """
    return function_2(data=data, template="/report.html")
```

Comment: Your function does not return a function, it return the *result* of function_2. So just copy its return type over. If it did actually return a function (which again it does not), you'd use [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable) as its type, as documented in [annotating callable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callables).